# Jest and supertest: Test keep exceeding timeout

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

Hello I am a bit confused by this error I have encountered.
I am working on an **Universal React App using Webpack 5 and Express.**

I want to implement **Jest** support by using the *React-testing-Library* for the frontend (which work) and *supertest* for the backend (this is where I am blocked).
I am following this basic [tutorial](https://www.albertgao.xyz/2017/05/24/how-to-test-expressjs-with-jest-and-supertest/) recommended by the jest doc himself in order to use jest on an node express environment.
But everytime I get this error:

> thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a test.
> Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."

Here are my code:

**server.js**

```
import app from './app.js';
import { mongooseConnection, disconnectMongoDB } from "./routers/services/url/urlDB.js"; // we call mongooseConnect var to connect only once into the mongoDB database
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080;


// the server listen on the port set by node on localhost.
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(
        `Server listening on \x1b[42m\x1b[1mhttp://localhost:${PORT}\x1b[0m in \x1b[41m${process.env.NODE_ENV}\x1b[0m`,
    );
});

// when when we shut down the app we execute a callback function before closing the server
process.on('exit', function() {
    disconnectMongoDB();
});
```

**app.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import path from 'path';
import cors from 'cors';
import {envIsProduction, envIsDevelopment} from './envmode/envUtil.js';
import { enableHMR } from './reload/hotReload.js';

let app = express();

// if we have set the environnent on production then:
if (envIsProduction()) {
    console.log(" _______________________________________ ");
    console.log("|                                       |");
    console.log("|             ( PRODUCTION )            |");
    console.log("|_______________________________________|");
    console.log(" ");

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname,'../client'))); // we serve static file like the bundle-app.js to the browser from the current directory where the server is executed and we move to the top root to access the file
}
else if (envIsDevelopment()) {
    console.log(" _______________________________________ ");
    console.log("|                                       |");
    console.log("|             ( DEVELOPMENT )           |");
    console.log("|_______________________________________|");
    console.log(" ");

    enableHMR(app); // we enable the Hot MPodule Reload on the frontend and the backend
}

app.use(cors());
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended:false}));
app.use(express.json());

//Hot reload!
//ALL server routes are in this module!
app.use((req, res, next) => {
    require("./routers/routers")(req, res, next);
});

export default app;
```

**routers.js**

```
import renderPage from "./renderpage/renderPage.js";
import { serverRoutes, reactRouterRoutes, getReactRouterRoutesString } from "./routes.js";
import express from "express";
import routerLoginDB from "./request/routerLoginDB.js";
import routerSignupDB from "./request/routerSignupDB.js";
const router = express.Router();

// Put all your server routes in here

// When the user connect to the root of the server we send the page
router.get(serverRoutes.root, renderPage);

// When the user send a get request by the /click route a console.log and a respone is send.
router.get(serverRoutes.click, (req, res)=>{
    res.status(200).send("Click");
});

// when this user want to login into his account, we ask for the routerLoginDB to handle it
router.post(serverRoutes.login,routerLoginDB);

// when this user want to signup into his account, we ask for the routerSignupDB to handle it
router.post(serverRoutes.signup, routerSignupDB);

// For all the routes that only react-router need to use, if we refresh on a nested route of the react-router from the client side then we redirect it to the root route "/"
router.get(reactRouterRoutes,(req,res) => {
  res.redirect("/");
});

router.get("*", (req,res) =>{
    res.status(404).send('page not found');
}); //For all other type of request excluding the one specified here, we send back a 404 page;

module.exports = router;
```

**app.test.js**

```
import request from '../utils/test-node-utils.js'

describe("Test the /click path", () => {
  test("It should response the GET method", () => {
    return request
      .get("/click")
      .expect(200);
  });
});
```

and finally **test-node-utils.js**

```
import supertest from "supertest";
import app from "../serverside/app.js";

const request = supertest(app);

export default request;
```

Don't believe what the error say because I think it is more deep than that.

I have tried to increased the jest timeout value but it keep being stuck and reach the timeout limit.
I have done exactly like the tutorial say without using my project structure and it worked but when I try to implement the tutorial in my backend structure, it don't work with supertest.
I think it is related to my files or backend structure that make it don't work with the test.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: What is `import request from '../utils/test-node-utils.js'`?

Comment: Oops sorry I forgot a file I update the post right away

Comment: It may be the case that your application is throwing untreated exceptions and crashing the server, causing the request you send with supertest never to be fulfilled. So the jest process keeps waiting for a response until it times out and exits the test. That's likely to happen when you setup your DB connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sorry for the late update, I solved this problem a long time ago and I forgot to add some more details in the initial post.
To be short, my app was using various technologies like **React-redux, mongoose and React-router.**
The tutorial was a bad idea because it was creating the same app with the same store and provider for every tests, so that might explain the huge latency.

Instead I needed to create a custom render function for the tests so that I create a new Redux store instance every time it's called, with an optional preloadedState value that can be used for an initial value
Alternately you could pass in an already-created Redux store instance
and it automatically wrap the component being tested with a `<Provider store={store}>`

Here is the function:

```
import React from 'react'
import { render } from '@testing-library/react'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { setupStore, persistor } from '../src/store/store.js';
import {BrowserRouter} from "react-router-dom";
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';

// Automatically create a store instance if no store was passed in
export function renderWithProviders(ui,{preloadedState = {},store = setupStore(preloadedState),...renderOptions} = {}) {
  function Wrapper({ children }) {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Provider store={store}>
            <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
              {children}
            </PersistGate>
          </Provider>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }

  return { store, ...render(ui, { wrapper: Wrapper, ...renderOptions }) }
```

For the backend I didn't use supertest at the end but did just make a fetch request to the serverUrl like this:

```
import fetch from 'cross-fetch';
import { serverUrl } from "./routers/routes.js"


// This test only test the click path
describe("Test the /click path", () => {
  test("It should response the GET method", async () => {
    const result = await fetch(`${serverUrl()}/click`).then(res => res.text());
    expect(result).toBe('Click');  // Success!
  });
});
```

Thank you for all of your help.

Answer (score 0):

I've recently debugged a similar issue where my Jest tests would run successfully (or not) in my dev. environment but when I would try and package the app as a Docker image all my tests would time out.

It turned out that by commenting out the line which setup CORS, which for me I only turned on in production builds (should have been a clue), the tests started to run again when building the image.

```
...
const NODE_ENV = process.env.NODE_ENV;
const app = express();
NODE_ENV.toUpperCase() === 'PRODUCTION' && app.use(cors);
...
```

I mentioned this as I can see from your snippet above that you are also using the [cors middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/resources/middleware/cors.html) and that, in your case, it's set all the time.

Perhaps not your issue, and you may want CORS in your tests for some reason, but try commenting it out and see if your tests run.